# How to refer a map column in a spark-sql query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

```
scala> val map1 = spark.sql("select map('p1', 's1', 'p2', 's2')")
```

map1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [map(p1, s1, p2, s2): map<string,string>]

```
scala> map1.show()

+--------------------+
| map(p1, s1, p2, s2)|
+--------------------+
|[p1 -> s1, p2 -> s2]|
+--------------------+
scala> spark.sql("select element_at(map1, 'p1')")
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`map1`' given
> input columns: []; line 1 pos 18; 'Project
> [unresolvedalias('element_at('map1, p1), None)]

How can we reuse the dataframe map1 in second sql query?

Comment: `element_at` takes a `column` argument. you are passing a dataframe to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map1` is a dataframe with a single column of type map. This column has the name `map(p1, s1, p2, s2)`. The dataframe can be queried for example with [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#selectExpr(exprs:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

```scala
map1.selectExpr("element_at(`map(p1, s1, p2, s2)`, 'p1')").show()
```

prints

```
+-----------------------------------+
|element_at(map(p1, s1, p2, s2), p1)|
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 s1|
+-----------------------------------+
```

Another option is to register the dataframe as temporary view and then use a sql query:

```scala
map1.createOrReplaceTempView("map1")
spark.sql("select element_at(`map(p1, s1, p2, s2)`, 'p1') from map1").show()
```

which prints the same result.