# How to do higher order function transform with sub query and a map lookup?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

This is a follow up question of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107171/how-to-refer-a-map-column-in-a-spark-sql-query)

```
scala> val map1 = spark.sql("select map('s1', 'p1', 's2', 'p2', 's3', 'p3') as lookup")
```

> map1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [lookup: map<string,string>]

```
scala> val ds1 = spark.sql("select 'p1' as p, Array('s2','s3') as c")
```

> ds1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [p: string, c: array]

```
scala>  ds1.createOrReplaceTempView("ds1")

scala> map1.createOrReplaceTempView("map1")

scala> map1.show()
+--------------------+
|              lookup|
+--------------------+
|[p1 -> s1, p2 -> ...|
+--------------------+


scala> ds1.show()
+---+--------+
|  p|       c|
+---+--------+
| p1|[s2, s3]|
+---+--------+

map1.selectExpr("element_at(`lookup`, 's2')").first()
```

> res50: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [p2]

```
scala> spark.sql("select element_at(`lookup`, 's1') from map1").show()
+----------------------+
|element_at(lookup, s1)|
+----------------------+
|                    p1|
+----------------------+
```

So far so good. In my next two steps I am hitting some issues:

```
scala> ds1.selectExpr("p", "c", "transform(c, cs -> map1.selectExpr('element_at(`lookup`, cs)')) as cs").show()
```

> 20/09/28 19:44:59 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name
> hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist 20/09/28 19:44:59 WARN
> HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist
> 20/09/28 19:45:03 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in
> metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so
> recording the schema version 2.3.0 20/09/28 19:45:03 WARN ObjectStore:
> setMetaStoreSchemaVersion called but recording version is disabled:
> version = 2.3.0, comment = Set by MetaStore root@10.1.21.76 20/09/28
> 19:45:03 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database map1, returning
> NoSuchObjectException org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Undefined function: 'selectExpr'. This function is neither a
> registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in
> the database 'map1'.; line 1 pos 19

```
scala> spark.sql("""select p, c, transform(c, cs -> (select element_at(`lookup`, cs) from map1)) cc from ds1""").show()
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`cs`' given
> input columns: [map1.lookup]; line 1 pos 61; 'Project [p#329, c#330,
> transform(c#330, lambdafunction(scalar-subquery#713 [], lambda cs#715,
> false)) AS cc#714] :  +- 'Project
> [unresolvedalias('element_at(lookup#327, 'cs), None)] :     +-
> SubqueryAlias map1 :        +- Project [map(s1, p1, s2, p2, s3, p3) AS
> lookup#327] :           +- OneRowRelation
> +- SubqueryAlias ds1    +- Project [p1 AS p#329, array(s2, s3) AS c#330]
> +- OneRowRelatio

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: I think `SelectExpr` is a function on Dataframe API and here you are trying to use it in Spark sql API which won't wprk

Comment: @Explorer You are right, I will edit that part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the table name to the `from` clauses.

```
spark.sql("""select p, c, transform(c, cs -> element_at(`lookup`, cs)) cc from ds1 a, map1 b""").show()

+---+--------+--------+
|  p|       c|      cc|
+---+--------+--------+
| p1|[s2, s3]|[p2, p3]|
+---+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If `map1` doesn't have too many rows, you could do a cross join with the set of all values extracted from the array(s) in the `c` columns.

```scala
spark.sql("select col as value, element_at(map1.lookup, col) as key +
          "from (select explode(ds1.c) from ds1) as v cross join map1")
```

Result (assigning the above to a value of type DataFrame, and calling `.show`):

```
+-----+---+
|value|key|
+-----+---+
|   s2| p2|
|   s3| p3|
+-----+---+
```